# webservice to return pdf with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a html to pdf conversion tool which resides on our server that I can access using a url with querystrings.
Something like myurl.com/createpdf.aspx?page=http://www.somesite.com.
The tool then converts the web page and displays it as a pdf.

I would like to offer this functionality as a web service, so that our clients can access this programmatically. 
Ideal case would be, that our clients send in the site they would like to have converted and the web service then returns the pdf.

Would that make sense?
What would be the best way to implement this?

cheers,

Terry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use file IO to read the PDF in and have your webmethod return it as a byte[] array. For example like this:

```
byte[] filebytes = null;
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
  filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
  fs.Read(filebytes, (int)0, (int)fs.Length);
}
return filebytes;
```

It will be Base64 encoded and you will then be able to Save and view the file on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write an http-handler that returns the pdf with the appropriate mime type. This way you would not have all the processing overhead of an aspx page.

Comment: He wouldn't anyway. It would be a webservice (asmx).

Comment: Well, when I read 'web service', I'm thinking proper web service. ;-)